# Should I give the interviewer a resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, new-job

I have a interview coming up very soon for a position as a Legal Secretary in a Law Firm. I am 19 years old. Freshman College student, just taking basic general ed. classes. NO experience as a secretary, personal assistant or anything related. Very minimal work history, all related to being a cashier. And I'm not an expert in Law. 
The primary reasons why I even got an interview scheduled is because of recommendations, my willingness to learn and my career interest to pursue an A.S. degree in Paralegal Studies. 
BTW The interviewer already knows all of this.

*Overall should make a resume? I feel it will be appropriate since it's a great position and opportunity for me, but I also feel I don't have much else to share. 
What should I do?!*

Comment: What have you done as student activities that demonstrates skills which will be valuable in the workplace? That can go on the resume, especially if it is a strong demonstration of the skills. "Coordinated a 20-person volunteer construction project, successfully framing, siding, and roofing a 40-foot by 80-foot dining hall in ten days of work" shows team management/leadership skills, for example -- especially if you can discuss the challenges and how you overcame them. "Treasurer for the campus lecture series, maintaining double-entry ledger books" shows another set of skills. And so on.

Comment: as the others note, make a resume - it makes you look "professional", which is useful in a law firm. Also, yes, bring it with you to the interview in some sort of sturdy folder (like the ones they use in legally blonde) to offer to the interviewer. Also, bring a few, just. in. case. The interviewer might not care much about your resume, but they might ask you have it, just to see how prepared you are.

Comment: *Usually* you'd have submitted a resume when applying so.. that's a little strange. I tend to keep spare, photocopied copies of *anything* relevant - school results, resumes and so on as a way of being prepared. So, yeah, since usually they would have it already, you *should* have a resume on hand.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you should make a résumé.

It will be short, but it will have your contact information on it, as well as the skills you purport to have.

This is an issue if, years down the line, you're still working for this lawfirm and someone accuses you of lying on your application.  HR (should) would have your original résumé on file and you would be able to show what you claimed at the time.

Kind of far-fetched, but as you'll soon learn in paralegal school (my wife is one), covering all the details pays off more often than not.

Answer (score 2):

@WesleyLong has it right. Make a resume, even if in your case, it is super short.

Think of your resume as a blank canvas. Over time, you will look at it periodically, reflect on where your career is going and review your goals for relevance to your life. And depending on what your goals are, you will fill up your resume with the skills and work experience you want to have.

Short term, you should write your resume even if you have very little to show. The very fact that you are writing it should create in you a desire for stronger work experience and skills set. I remember how pathetic my first resume was :)

In terms of managing your career, you are running a marathon not a sprint athough you will be surging forward at keys points of the race.

Comment: and the race has no real end, and many different ways to "win", and the people who are watching you are also in the race too, and there are much much less support staff on hand in case something goes wrong, and you get to leave the race at any time, but it keeps on going on without you, and you can always reenter it.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest a more positive outlook on this wonderful opportunity as a student. As you say the personal already knows .... but you still need it in writing for your file and other people consulted for many and various reasons. You stated it perfectly ...  ' .. my willingness to learn and my career interest to pursue an A.S. degree in Paralegal Studies. ' Be positive, try to approach them and your writing as this is what I've done in school and will do and this is what I can do for you while I'm doing all that.  I hope that helps. Congrats.